# Filter search bar for tickets by message

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, searchbar

I'm on a project using Laravel and I'm kinda new to this framework.
I would like to know if there is a way to create a search bar that filters my table according to one of the tds. The table cells are filled from database so it's not static data. I have only found answers for static datas so far using Javascript.

Here is my table:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered" id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Objet</td>
        <td>Urgence</td>
        <td>Statut</td>
        <td>Utilisateur</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
      </tr>
      @foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
        <tr>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->message}}</td>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->urgence->niveau}}</td>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->statut}}</td>
        <td width="25%">{{ $ticket->utilisateur->name}}</td>
        <td style='white-space: nowrap'>
          <a href="{{ url('tickets/'.$ticket->id.'/voir')}}" class="btn btn-info">Voir</a>
          <a href="{{ url('tickets/'.$ticket->id.'/delete')}}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Êtes vous sûr de vouloir supprimmer ce ticket?')">Supprimer</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach

    </table>
    {{ $tickets->render()}}
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use ajax i guess and then reload the table according to the response. Of just use dataTables and use the ajax as described in the docs there. Tbh this has nothing to do with laravel and everything to do with javascript and how you decided to implement the tables

Comment: Where can i find documentation to be able to do so? I have never used AJAX.

Comment: Have you tried using Datatables:  https://datatables.net/?

Comment: No I haven't, is it open source? Because this project is actually an internship project and I will have to present it.